# Getting stuck in self-study in math heavy field: how to look for collaborators?

Tags: soft-question, advice

I have been self-studying some topics in theoretical statistics and find that I often come across questions that are very difficult for me to answer, even with days of work and reading. Sometimes they are exercises from some text, but often they are my own questions about a claim in a paper. I usually post these questions here if they are self-contained enough, but often they are not. And even then they often go unanswered, even with a bounty.

My strategy is to note these questions down and then try to address them again later, sometimes I can answer them on a second or third attempt, but often I can never answer them. It's unfortunate since these questions usually feel like a great learning opportunity for me.

Usually I would discuss with someone else interested in the subject, but since this is self-study, I usually do not know anyone who is interested in the same questions/topics as me.

I have seen several questions on this site about "getting stuck", and those threads have been very helpful. My question is different from these:

- Would it be reasonable for me to seek out a tutor/coach at this level? I think I would only need a few hours a month of discussion. How would I find and approach someone with such an offer/request? Another option would be to find someone at my level (or slightly above my level) to work with on some similar topics, but I don't know how to find such a person.
- Since my topic is theoretical statistics, it doesnt fit perfectly in this SE or in CrossValidated (which tends to be much more applied and less theoretical). Where is the better place to ask such questions? For example see any of the unanswered questions in my profile.